# Reading from double array of pointers - NULL

Tags: c++

My method replaces cells in the double array _board.
After the replacement it sets the cell to NULL.

In the next call for the cell that was set to NULL it doesnt recognize it as NULL.

((_board[location.getX()][location.getY()]==NULL))

And keeps on with the method then reading trash

Whats wrong?

```
    void Board::MovePiece(Point location, Move m) throw (GameEndException, OutOfBoundsException, InvalidMoveException, NonEmptySquareException)
{
    int i,j;
    bool flag1,flag2;
    if **(_board[location.getX()][location.getY()]==NULL)**{
        InvalidMoveException IO;
        throw IO;}
    if ((_board[location.getX()][location.getY()]->IsValidMove(m)==false)||(_board[location.getX()][location.getY()]->getPlayerNum()!=GetTurn())) {
        InvalidMoveException IO;
        throw IO;}
    if (_board[location.getDestination(m).getX()][location.getDestination(m).getY()]!=NULL) {
        if (_board[location.getDestination(m).getX()][location.getDestination(m).getY()]->getPlayerNum()==GetTurn()){
        NonEmptySquareException IO;
        throw IO;}}
        Point tmp=location.getDestination(m);
        _board[tmp.getX()][tmp.getY()]=_board[location.getX()][location.getY()]->Clone();
        delete _board[location.getX()][location.getY()];
        _board[location.getX()][location.getY()]=NULL;
    _lastM=m;
    _lastP=location;
                flag1=false;
                flag2=false;
        for (i=0;i<BOARD_SIZE;i++){
            for (j=0;j<BOARD_SIZE;j++){
                if(_board[i][j]!=NULL){
                if (_board[i][j]->getPlayerNum()==ONE) flag1=true;
                if (_board[i][j]->getPlayerNum()==TWO) flag2=true;
                }}}
        if ((flag1==false)||(flag2==false)){
            GameEndException IO;
        throw IO;}
}
```

Comment: This would not pass code review, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Here `delete _board[location.getX()][location.getY()];` you have deleted the location and You are trying to access deleted memory location.

Comment: Right after that the method sets it to NULL
BTW it doesnt work even without this code line

Comment: Now what is the issue? Can you elaborate a bit that exactly where you are getting error?

Comment: In the second run, it gets to the cell that was deleted... and the line: _board[location.getX()][location.getY()]==NULL  is not true. it considers it as false. but in the first run it sets it to NULL...
_board is double array of pointers

Comment: Don't delete the cell and there must be some problem in your logic that I can't tell without knowing how you are calling it in first/second run and what values you are passing.